# How to set Checkbox cheked value to textview in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

I am new in android, i have created alert dialog box on that i kept check boxes for selecting multiple week days, after checking days on check box i need to set those selected days to text view. I searched a lot for that but i don't found satisfactory answer please anyone can help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to remove the check boxes and replace them with the TextView on selecting the checkbox? This question is very vague. Can you edit your question with the some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(checkBox.isSelected()){
String s = checkBox.getText().toString();
}
```

This way you can get Value of all of you checkbox.

At last you can set that string value to your `textview`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
checkBox.setSelected(selected);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need to set that checked multiple values to textview, how can i achieve it?

Comment: check this example : http://suvendugiri.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/android-using-checkbox-with-example/